# Magento product tier prices are deleted on product images update

Tags: magento

I have created a script to update programmatically my products pictures but my script delete all tier_prices on `$product->save();`

Here is my bilder update script :

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {

    $formatted_sku = $product->getSku();
    $config = $product->getMediaConfig();



    // JPG files verification
    $jpg_file = $images_folder.$formatted_sku.".".$extension[0];
    if (file_exists($jpg_file) ) {
        $fileurl = $config->getMediaUrl($jpg_file);
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($jpg_file, $visibility, false, false);
        $product->save();

    }
}
```

How can I avoid the update of my tier_prices ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you that are still running into this issue, there is a simple fix to try. It looks like the tierprice data is not read by the default getModel for the product.  To fix this, just call the product's getTierPrice method to load it.

```
$tp=$product->getTierPrice();
```

You don't have to do anything else, just load it.  Then when you save the product, the tiered pricing data is saved.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem. I finally work it out in a very weird way, but it definitely worked. You just need to create a "fake" tierprice:

```
$tierPrices = array(
              'website_id'  => 0,
              'cust_group'  => 2,
              'price_qty'   => 3,
              'price'       => 10
             );
```

(note that there are no [ ])

Then add it (it won't add anything actually), but you need to do this:

```
$product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
```

And finally save the product:

```
$product->save();
```

It will save your product without deleting your old tier prices. Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks, i found to update a products tier, you can use this:   $product->setTierPrice();
  $product->save();
  $product->setTierPrice($tier); 
  $product->save();

Answer (score 0):

How do you created that `$productCollection`? Maybe product was not populated with needed data (tier_prices) so `save()` persist product without that data. Try to add some attributes to select with `addAttributeToSelect()`

Comment: In the begenning I have used : 
$productCollection = `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');`
and then I have added `->addAttributeToFilter` to test with only one product like this :

`
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('SKU', 'SA80/80');
`
but I get always the same result.

Comment: maybe you need to do something like this `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('SKU', 'SA80/80');`

Comment: I still need heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp !! :(

Comment: Bizboss did you solve this in the end ? I've run a script on 500 products and lost tier prices.

Answer (score 0):

The comments of others on this post helped to lead me to a solution that worked.  For me, simply setting the tier price to false is what was needed to prevent it from being overwritten/modified.

```
$product->setTierPrice(false);
```

I personally prefer this option over some of the other solutions as it's clean, simple, doesn't set fake values, and it works.  To those points, I would have preferred it if the solution presented by GregC would have worked as it's simply loading the tier price, but in my testing that did not work as expected - the tier price was still deleted.

Here would be the modified version of the code from the OP.

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $formatted_sku = $product->getSku();
    $config = $product->getMediaConfig();

    // JPG files verification
    $jpg_file = $images_folder.$formatted_sku.".".$extension[0];
    if (file_exists($jpg_file) ) {
        $fileurl = $config->getMediaUrl($jpg_file);
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($jpg_file, $visibility, false, false);
        $product->setTierPrice(false);  // set tier price to false to prevent it from being overwritten
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

This code was tested and used with Magento EE 1.14.12.0