# After Update product attribute, vanishes tier prices - magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I tried to update product's attribute called barcode as follows.

It update the product but cleared tier price of that product. Please help me.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $prod_sku);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

if ($product) {
  $product->setBarcode($bar_code);
  $product->save();
 }
```

Comment: I got an answer from Marius. Please refer that. I have added it below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(! $product->save()){
```

makes little sense as the `!` is telling if NOT TRUE product must have been saved....but a successfull saved product is returning `$this` which is seen as true for the IF-clause without the expression mark.

I guess your problem is completely related to another technical problem...

EDIT: There seems to be some weird problem have a look at this...sounds strange but give it a try [Magento product tier prices are deleted on product images update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872988/magento-product-tier-prices-are-deleted-on-product-images-update)

Comment: Thanks for reply Mischa. I have edited the code. The problem was, it clears all tier prices. Is there any workaround for this.. Thanks.

Comment: I got an answer from Marius. Please refer that. I have added it below.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) for [my question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/after-update-product-attribute-vanishes-tier-prices) in magento statckoverflow. Thanks Marius.I'm going to add it here for reference.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($prod_sku);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
if ($product) {
  $product->setBarcode($bar_code);
  if(! $product->save()){
            $productId = $product->getId();
            echo "product_Id :: ".$productId." - Product sku :: ".$product->getSku()."<br />";
        }else{
            echo "not saved";
        }
 }
```